# AJax Internal Server Error 500

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have a page method issue I have this page method on a ASP.net webform

```
   [WebMethod(true)]
    public static int GetInt(int id){
          return 10;
   }
```

and I call it from JQuery like this

```
   $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "webforms.aspx/GetInt",
            data: "{id:'1'}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) {
            },
            error: function (err) {
            }
        });
```

This all works just fine, when I put a break point on the server side it hits, but for some odd reason I after the PageMethod returns, I get the error call back of the ajax call never success! Any ideas.

I cant use a script manager on this one! I open to any cross browser solution!.

Comment: Look at the actual HTTP response (in your dev tools) and read the error.

Comment: Try removing `dataType: "json",`

Comment: The reponse offered no help. It had the same error message. Removing the dataType did not help either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used your code and am having no issues. Here is my exact code:

WebForm1.aspx

```
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>

</div>
</form>

<script>
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/WebForm1.aspx/GetInt",
        data: "{id:'1'}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (msg) {
            alert("SUCCESS: " + msg.d);
        },
        error: function (err) {
            alert("FAILURE");
        }
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

WebForm1.aspx.cs

```
using System.Web.Services;


namespace WebApplication3
{
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    [WebMethod(true)]
    public static int GetInt(int id)
    {
        return 10;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks, for your efforts, It may be just some thing going on with my local install of IIS, after I tried is on developement server it worked as expected. It was the strangest thing, and it is very stupid of me to have blown 4 hours on such a simple problem.

Comment: You know, I have seen this happen when using breakpoints. If you look at your code too long and hit resume, you will get the error function of the ajax call. I'm not sure why, maybe a timeout. Glad I could help!